# Can't export 2nd function from nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am making google authentication using nodejs, express and passport. I am almost done but I have wrote a function where if the user is not logged in, then It should redirect to home page and it is not working. The code in router file is following:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user.js');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'sprinklrExchange' });
});

router.get('/ask', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index2', { title: 'sprinklrExchange' });
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('profile.ejs', { user: req.user });
});

router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

    // the callback after google has authenticated the user
router.get('/auth/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google', {
                successRedirect : '/profile',
                failureRedirect : '/'
        }));

router.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }

    // console.log("hello world");
    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

Whenever I am redirecting to `localhost:3000/profile` without logging in, it shows the following (instead redirecting me to homepage):

[image]

profile.ejs :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; word-wrap:break-word; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1><span class="fa fa-anchor"></span> Profile Page</h1>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <!-- GOOGLE INFORMATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well">
                <h3 class="text-danger"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span> Google</h3>

                    <p>
                        <strong>id</strong>: <%= user.google.id %><br>
                        <strong>token</strong>: <%= user.google.token %><br>
                        <strong>email</strong>: <%= user.google.email %><br>
                        <strong>name</strong>: <%= user.google.name %>
                    </p>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give the content of file `profile.ejs`.

Comment: @BlackMamba updated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are using your `isLoggedIn()` function anywhere.

Comment: @mscdex I don't know how to use that. I am newbie to node. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem is that:
when you access `localhost:3000/profile` without logging in, the `req.user` is undefined, so you cann't do `user.google.id`.